# How to disable select optgroup (groupbox)?

Tags: php, jquery

How to disable select optgroup (groupbox) ? i want to disable to select group checkbox.

http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/multiple-select/docs/

```
<form action="show.php" method="post">
    <select name="test[]" multiple="multiple" id="duo">
      <optgroup label="UAE">
      <option value="18">Abu Dhabi</option>
      <option value="19">Dubai</option>
      </optgroup>
      <optgroup label="UK">
      <option value="22">Birmingham</option>
      <option value="94">Brighton</option>
      <option value="24">Leeds</option>
      <option value="99">Liverpool</option>
      <option value="21">London</option>
      <option value="85">Luton</option>
      <option value="23">Manchester</option>
      </optgroup>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </form>

    @import url('http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/multiple-select/multiple-select.css');
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/multiple-select/jquery.multiple.select.js"></script>

    <script>
        $("#duo").multipleSelect({
            placeholder: "Here is the placeholder",
            width: 200,
            selectAll: false,
            filter: true,
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The tag `optgroup` accepts the attribute `disabled`.

```
<select name="test[]" multiple="multiple" id="duo">
    <optgroup label="UAE" disabled>
        <option value="18">Abu Dhabi</option>
        <option value="19">Dubai</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wg1c0kfn/)

**Reference**

[optgroup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup)

Answer (score 1):

You should add `disable` prop to `optgroup`. Try something like this:

```
$('[label=UAE]').prop('disabled', 'disabled')
```

In HTML markup it must be:

```
<select name="test[]" multiple="multiple" id="duo">
      <optgroup label="UAE" disabled>
        <option value="18">Abu Dhabi</option>
        <option value="19">Dubai</option>
      </optgroup>
      <optgroup label="UK">
        <option value="22">Birmingham</option>
        <option value="94">Brighton</option>
      </optgroup>
</select>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/g49tbeq9/)**